# How to publish XML file for data access for android application?

Tags: xml

I am creating android app and i need to publish on some free server xml file. 
I tried to publish on couple free servers, but when i open the url via browser the file downloads to my pc and also app cannot access the data. I want to do something just like this:

http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12718298&u=c

Content of the file looks like this:
http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/catalogs/1day-M2.5.xml

I want to do the same like for the link before .

If anybody knows how to solve this problem, please write down !

Thanks a lot !

Comment: " i need to publush on some free server xml file." -- You mean accessing it? Or creating it?

Comment: I mean accessing it!! I already have created the file.

Comment: you need to specify the mime type in the response i think. how is this related to android, again ?

Comment: The idea first of all is to have access for android app. Some period of time ago it worked fine on one free server but they changed something one their servers and problem appears. Access via browser was the same like for the link i mention before! And now i want to have the same access, to read the content of the file via browser, not to automaticly be downloaded to my computer if i visit the file.

Comment: What about, instead of accessing it via browser, making a HTTP request for it and displaying the response in a WebView or process it however you want?